# input_table._get_numeric_data() doesn’t work in python predictor. What do I do to fix it?

Tags: python, knime

I am getting such an error in the Python Predicator node while running my workflow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQR30.png)

The error is like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Yq4.png)

When I look at the previous node I see there is sampleID. It exists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIhWI.png)

But I realized that the problem is not about this.
This line in the code doesn’t work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZiRy.png)

new_data = input_table._get_numeric_data()

So ._get_numeric_data() doesn’t work in this Python code. It shows as an Object type.

I am using Mac OS. Do you have any idea about solving the problem?

I am trying to execute my workflow in KNIME. And I am getting this error in the Python predicator. I don't know if my error is because the Python predictor is deprecated but I couldn't find a way to convert object to numerical data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors